# Given matrix $3\times3$ $A$ such that $\rho(A-2I)< \rho(A+I)$and $A(1,2,-3)^t=(-1,-2,3)^t$ prove that A is diagonalizable (explanation of a solution)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given matrix $3\times3$ $A$ such that $\rho(A-2I)< \rho(A+I)$and $A(1,2,-3)^t=(-1,-2,3)^t$ prove that A is diagonalizable $(\rho=rank)$

---

The solution in the textbook:

Given the matrix $A$ that satisfies $\rho(A-2I)< \rho(A+I)$ and
$A\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  2\\
  -3\\
\end{array}
\right)$
$=$
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  -1\\
  -2\\
  3\\
\end{array}
\right)$

we can get that $(-1)$ is an eigenvalue and $\rho(-I-A)\leq2$ therefore $\rho(A+I)\leq2$

$\rho(A-2I)=0$ cannot happen because if $\rho(A-2I)=0$ then $A=2I$ and then we cannot have $(-1)$ eigenvalue , from here $\rho(A-2I) \geq1$ and from the information $\rho(A-2I)< \rho(A+I)$ and $\rho(A+I) \leq2$ we only have one option $\rho(A-2I)=1$ and $\rho(A+I)=2$ so $2$ is also an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $2$ and $(-1)$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity of $1$ , the sum of the geometric multiplicities is $3$ therefore it is diagonalizable.

My questions:

Could we find the eigenvalues this way?

According to given information $\rho(A-2I)< \rho(A+I)$ $\qquad$ $\rho(A+I)\leq3$ so $\rho(A-2I)\leq 2$ we can find the eigenvalues by $\det(-I-A)$ and $\det(2I-A)$ so we have $val_1=-1$ and $val_2 =2$

Question about the rank on why $\rho(A+I)\leq 2$

I know this solution is detailed but I did not understand some stuff such as why $\rho(A+I)\leq 2$ ? isn't it supposed to be  $\rho(A+I)\leq 3$ ? how did they conclude that from the given information

last question about the geometric multiplicity , did they find it by $dim(P)=n-\rho(A)$? then for $\rho(A-2I)$ they did $dim(P)=3-1=2$ and for $\rho(A+I)=2$ $dim(P)=3-2=1$

Thank you!.

Comment: $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore $A+I$ is singular. Since $A+I$ is $3\times3$, its rank is at most $2$. Also, when the rank of $A-2I$ is $1$, its nullity is $2$. Therefore $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A-2I$ with geometric multiplicity $2$. This means $2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with geometric multiplicity $2$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you , but isn't a matrix singular if and only if it has an eigenvalue $0$ therefore the determinant is also zero?
how do we know if it is singular if it has eigenvalue $-1$

Comment: I meant $A+I$ is singular, not that $A$ is singular. If $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A+I$.